# vagrant: a better to way to "reset" my guest vagrant vm's network?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I am relatively new to vagrant but certainly liking it so far.

One of the little problem I often face is that when my host machine's network goes down momentarily, it affects my connection to my vagrant guest vm.

When my host machine's network comes back up again, I have to - on my host machine - run `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up` in order to "reset" my guest vagrant vm's network so that it can connect to the internet once again.

Is there a more "elegant" way of getting my vm's internet connection via my host machine's network to detect that the internet network connection is back up?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the easiest solution is to restart the networking subsystem within the VM itself. SSH connections shouldn't be interrupted. On Ubuntu, do the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: For my case using Debian and `config.vm.network :public_network,  bridge: 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'` in `Vagrantfile` I need to do: `sudo ifdown eth2 && sudo ifup eth2`

Answer (score 3):

Regarding what Mitchell answers, for my Vagrant version 1.5.2 the command is little different:

sudo /etc/init.d/network restart

Instead of using "networking". I know is not a big deal, but  just wanted to say it.

Great work with Vagrant Mitchell!

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment

Comment: Possibly you are on a CentOS/Red Hat/Fedora VM rather than an Ubuntu / Debian one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i did:

HOST=VM IP Address
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH= Private key path

`ssh vagrant@$HOST -i $PRIVATE_KEY_PATH` to login to the VM

Then, `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Answer (score 0):

Updated version (year 2018) of the command listed in other answers*:

For Ubuntu 16.04.* LTS (Xenial Xerus):

```
sudo systemctl restart networking

# Check the status - there is no better way with systemd for now:
# https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1287
sudo systemctl status networking
```

For CentOS 7.5 (`network` vs `networking` is quite unfortunate difference, but here we are):

```
sudo systemctl restart network

# Check the status - there is no better way with systemd for now:
# https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1287
sudo systemctl status network
```

*In modern distributions scripts listed in the answers are just wrappers around `systemd`'s `systemctl`.