# Kubernetes dashboard proxy stops working after time passes - no route to host

Tags: proxy, kubernetes, dashboard, kubectl

I'm using kubernetes proxy to talk to my kube dashboard

I'm running kubernetes on vagrant

In the browser I usually see the dashboard, but after some time passes I end up with the following instead in the browser:

```
Error: 'dial tcp 10.2.99.7:9090: getsockopt: no route to host'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.2.99.7:9090/'
```

At the same time in the terminal I see:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.17.4.101:443
Heapster is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
KubeDNS is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
```

The only way I can find to fix this so far is to do a `vagrant halt && vagrant up` but this is quite disruptive.

I've tried killing and restarting `kubectl proxy` - does not change the situation.

All of this is running on a MacOSX laptop btw.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [vagrant: a better to way to “reset” my guest vagrant vm's network?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378185/vagrant-a-better-to-way-to-reset-my-guest-vagrant-vms-network)

Comment: have you tried minikube? Or, if you need multi node k8s cluster, github.com/TheNewNormal/kube-cluster-osx ?

Comment: Thank you @pagid I am going to using this command `$ vagrant ssh w1 -c 'sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd'` but I have to wait for the problem to happen again. If it works I'll come back and create the answer here.

Comment: Vincent, I will try out your suggestions, especially the native kube cluster

Comment: Any chance your vagrant host machine went to sleep/suspend? That sometimes (but not consistently) interferes with the docker service that is running on the guests. Next time try a systemctl docker restart (it's a quick operation).

Comment: Janos, it is very possible. I will try your suggestion. Restarting networkd did not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, restarting the docker daemon is not inexpensive for me as I am running several containers on the VM. It does fix the problem, but is no less disruptive than vagrant halt and up